# How do I determine which of the given quantity systems corresponds to an event algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given is the set $\Omega =\left \{ 3,4,5 \right \}$

How do I determine which of the given quantity systems corresponds to an event algebra?

$ \left \{\left \{  \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4 \right \},\left \{  5\right \},\left \{  3,4\right \},\left \{  3,5\right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{  3,4,5\right \}\right \}$

$\left \{\left \{  \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \}\right \}$

$ \left \{\left \{  \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{  3,4,5\right \}\right \}$

$ \left \{\left \{  \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4 \right \},\left \{  5\right \},\left \{  3,4\right \},\left \{  3,5\right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{  3,4,5\right \}\right \}$

To check which of these systems constitute an event algebra, you need only check that they are closed under countable Boolean operations.

So I think that $ \left \{\left \{  \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4 \right \},\left \{  5\right \},\left \{  3,4\right \},\left \{  3,5\right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{  3,4,5\right \}\right \}$ corresponds to an event algebra.

Is that only correct answer or?

Answer (score 1):

The collection $\mathcal{A}=\left \{\left \{  \right \},\left \{ 3 \right \},\left \{ 4 \right \},\left \{  5\right \},\left \{  3,4\right \},\left \{  3,5\right \},\left \{ 4,5 \right \},\left \{  3,4,5\right \}\right \}$ of subsets of $\Omega =\left \{ 3,4,5 \right \}$ satisfies:

(a) $\;\Omega\in \mathcal{A}$.
 
(b) $\;A\in \mathcal{A}\Rightarrow A^c\in \mathcal{A}.$
(c) $\;A,B\in \mathcal{A}\Rightarrow A\cup B \in \mathcal{A}.$

So, $\mathcal{A}$ is an event algebra, in this concrete case, $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. Try the rest.